# "XSD Not Valid" but how?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have run the following XSD through a few online XSD validators but none of them tell me
what is wrong with my XSD. It just says "XSD Not Valid". Any help identifying the issue or
point me to a site that might help me to identify the issue. This is only
my 2nd XSD so I am not surprised that it is not correct in some way.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
               <xsd:element name='DemandData'>
                 <xsd:complexType> 
                   <xsd:sequence>  
                      <xsd:element name='RateInformation' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='5000'>  
                           <xsd:complexType>      
                              <xsd:all>
                                <xsd:element name='RateID' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1'>
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                                      <xsd:minLength value='19'/>
                                       <xsd:maxLength value='19'/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name='RateName' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                <xsd:element name='RatePlan_Url' minOccurs='0' nillable='true' maxOccurs='1' />
                                <xsd:element name='RateType' minOccurs='1' nillable='true' maxOccurs='1'>
                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                            <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='R-D' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='C-D' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='V-D' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='CPP' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='VPP' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='RTP' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='DSR' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='TOU' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='T-D' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='GHG' />
                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                       </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element><xsd:element name='Sector' minOccurs='0' nillable='true' maxOccurs='1'>
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                                            <xsd:enumeration value='CEV' />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value='Ind' />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value='Res' />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value='Agr' />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value='All' />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value='REV' />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value='Com' />
                                            <xsd:enumeration value='CIA' />
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name='API_Url' minOccurs='0' nillable='true' maxOccurs='1' />
                                <xsd:element name='EndUse' minOccurs='0' nillable='true' maxOccurs='1' />
                                        <xsd:simpleType>
                                            <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='All' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='EV' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='Other' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='Solar' />
                                                <xsd:enumeration value='Battery' />
                                            </xsd:restriction>
                                        </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name='PriceInformation'>   
                                    <xsd:complexType> 
                                        <xsd:sequence> 
                                            <xsd:element name='PriceData'>   
                                                <xsd:complexType>      
                                                    <xsd:all>
                                                        <xsd:element name='DateStart' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                        <xsd:element name='DateEnd' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                        <xsd:element name='DayStart' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                        <xsd:element name='DayEnd' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                        <xsd:element name='Price' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                        <xsd:element name='PriceName' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                        <xsd:element name='TimeStart' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                        <xsd:element name='TimeEnd' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                        <xsd:element name='Unit' minOccurs='1' nillable='false' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                    </xsd:all>
                                                </xsd:complexType>
                                            </xsd:element>
                                        </xsd:sequence>
                                    </xsd:complexType>
                                </xsd:element>
                              </xsd:all>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>      
                 </xsd:complexType>  
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:schema>
```

Here is a link to one of the validators I was getting the XSD syntax error with:
https://extendsclass.com/xml-schema-validator.html

Comment: Please give more info. how are you validating ? example xml ?

Comment: Just to be clear, I am not getting a validation error but a problem with the XSD syntax itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most XSD processors would have at least detected that the closing `xsd:element` tag just before `PriceInformation`,

```
        <xsd:element name='EndUse' minOccurs='0' nillable='true' maxOccurs='1' />
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base='xsd:string'>
            <xsd:enumeration value='All' />
            <xsd:enumeration value='EV' />
            <xsd:enumeration value='Other' />
            <xsd:enumeration value='Solar' />
            <xsd:enumeration value='Battery' />
          </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>  <!-- Parsing realizes something is wrong here -->
      <xsd:element name='PriceInformation'>
```

lacked a matching start tag – this is just basic well-formedness checking at the XML level.

The issue is that what was intended to be the matching start tag for that `xsd:element` close tag was mistakenly self-closed:

```
      <xsd:element name='EndUse' minOccurs='0' nillable='true' maxOccurs='1' />
                                                                             ^
```

remove that  `/` character, and the XSD will then be well-formed.

Comment: wow, days of looking over this XSD and I never found that one character out of place. I feel stupid but so glad you found this and helped me tremendously.

Comment: It's hard for a parsing-related tool to identify the exact problem, but yours owed you more feedback than just *XSD Not Valid*.  Without you knowing at least that a particular closing tag was unmatched, spotting the issue would be extremely difficult.   Offline tools such as those based on Xerces or anything from Saxonica tend to provide much more helpful error messages.